# Locus if three lines are concurrent

Tags: geometry

If the three distinct lines

$$\begin{align}
  x + 2 a y + a & = 0 \\
  x + 3 b y + b & = 0 \\
  x + 4 a y + a & = 0
\end{align}$$

are concurrent, then the point (a, b) lies on a :-

(1) circle (2) straight line
(3) parabola (4) hyperbola

I try to solve two equation of line and put the values of x ,y in third equation . but it is getting very long , is there any other method .

I think there would be some method to solve it with matrix

Comment: By first & third we have $ay=0$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee that's a nice one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT.

For the system of equations to have solution, the matrix of coefficients must have vanishing determinant:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2a & a \\
1 & 3b & b \\
1 & 4a & a \\
\end{vmatrix}=0.
$$